# forgetting to declare variables

Tags: python, interpreter

If inside a loop, is it possible to instantiate objects to be manipulated during subsequent iterations of the loop, and still available when the scope of the loop has been left?

Here is a simple example of what I thought might work:

```
>>> for i in range(2):
...   r = [] if r is None else r
...   r.append[i]
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
NameError: name 'r' is not defined
```

And here's my second attempt using a NameError exception:

```
>>> for i in range(2):
...   try:
...     r = r
...   except NameError:
...     r = []
...   r.append(i)
...
>>>
```

<strike>I suspect that what I have been trying to do is actually prohibited, but I don't understand why it would be.</strike>

Can someone throw some light on this for me please?

Edit:

So the second way works, but it's very long winded.  Is there a quick way?

Comment: I recognise that it defeats the point of the question but you could of course instantiate it before the loop?

Comment: What's the advantage over simply defining `r = []` before the loop that you're hoping to get?

Comment: @Ben and DSM, it's partly the satisfaction of something working on the first try! But also not having to abort code entry because I've forgotten to define.  In addition, I'm usually just seeing if something works, and I seem to retype lots because of it.

Comment: Why not r = [i for i in range(2)] ? Anyway it's good practice to define vars at the beginning of the block.

Comment: @f p: Why not `r = list(range(2))` (Python 3) or `r = range(2)` (Python 2)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find out if the name is in your locals like this: `name in locals()` Regarding your question:

```
>>> 'r' in locals()
False
>>> for i in range(2):
    if 'r' not in locals(): r = []
    r.append(i)


>>> r
[0, 1]
>>>
```

I agree with Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams; this is not good style. Please do what you need to before looping.

Comment: +1 This is a brilliant answer. I promise not to use it in code and only when playing in the interpreter :-)

Answer (score 6):

It's not prohibited, but it is actively discouraged. `NameError` should *never* be caught barring extreme circumstances; always bind the name outside the loop even if to `None`.

Comment: just noticed i had square brackets instead of parenthesis... fixed... update to follow